# cypher conditional match inside where

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find a way to write the following (probably simple) query

```
match (user:User) 
where  NOT((user)--(a:Type)--(b))
OR ((user)--(a:Type)--(b) AND a.value >1000)
```

the above of course is pseudo and will not work

Comment: actually this query should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only create variables in the `MATCH` clause here, so let's treat the conditional as an `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead:

```
MATCH (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)--(a:Type)--(b)
WHERE a IS NULL
   OR a.value > 1000
RETURN user, a, b
```